# Postfix Relay Access Denied

Tags: postfix

I have my postfix server running with MySQL and squirrelmail, and everything works fine, however when I attempt to send an e-mail from a remote client, I get a relay access denied error, after much googling, I haven't really found anything that solves my problem, I would  be grateful for any help that you can give.

```
me@my-server:~$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
delay_warning_time = 4h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
mydestination = my-server, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = my_domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 OTHER_NETWORK HOME_NETWORK
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.comcast.net]:587
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to authenticate to postfix so that relaying is allowed. Configure this in you mail client.
If it does not work look at the related questions here about configuring postfix and SASL.

Answer (score 0):

You neet to change the mynetworks entry to allow this.

Please see the documentation here http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks

Comment: What if I want the networks to not be defined, but rather to have anyone who can authenticate to be able to send messages?